# Python Server NameError: global name 'SocketError' is not defined

Tags: python, kivy

I wanted to make a connection between a sever and a client, so the server sends a string to the client.

**Here is the Server:**

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = '190.176.141.23'#ip changed
    port = 12345

    while True:

        s = socket.socket()
        s.bind((host,port))

        s.listen(1)
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print "Connection from: " + str(addr)


        command = c.recv(1024)

        if command == 'GIVETEXT':
            c.send('test')

        try:
            c.close()
            sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        except SocketError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
                raise
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

**And here is the Client I made:**

```
import socket

class Client(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.s = socket.socket()

    def sent(self, host, port):
        self.s.connect((host, port))
        self.s.send('GIVETEXT')
        self.Text = self.s.recv(1024)
        print self.Text
        self.s.close
        return self.Text
```

Needless to say, that I executed the method in another piece of code, and it worked. But after that the server crashed, with the error message:

```
NameError: global name 'SocketError' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [`socket.error`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.error); not `SocketError`. Change your `except` line to:

```
except socket.error as e:
```